# Oracle Apex regexp pass as bind variable failing in function

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a function to find out regexp_like for the given variable.
When i run it as

> select func_name('ABC123','^[[:alpha:]]{3,3}[[:digit:]]{3,3}$') from
> dual;

it returns TRUE and if instead of ABC123 i use ABC1234 it returns FALSE.

However, if i use bind variables :

> select regex_func_name(:NAME,:FORMAT) from
> dual;

And pass :NAME = ABC123 and :FORMAT = '^[[:alpha:]]{3,3}[[:digit:]]{3,3}$' it returns FALSE in any scenario.

How can i pass bind variable correctly?
I tried passing :NAME in quote, i.e. 'ABC123', but nothing is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that you're using Apex **SQL Workshop**. If so, it - for some reason (unknown to me) - **cuts** bind variable at 14th character.

Yes - you can copy/paste its full contents (this: `^[[:alpha:]]{3,3}[[:digit:]]{3,3}$`) into bind variable's item, but it is actually cut. How do I know? Hit Run again, and you'll see pre-populated values you used previously.

[image]

If you shorten `NAME` to `ABC` and modify `FORMAT` to `[[:alpha:]]{3}`, query returns value.

Besides that, there's no problem in your query; you can execute it *as is*, pass those values (without single quotes!) to other GUI tools such as TOAD and everything works just fine.

I tried to find reference to Apex' bind variable's *limits* (specially its length), but couldn't find anything. Maybe it is a *feature*, but I'd rather think of it as a *bug*.